# How to fix MUI Snackbar/Toast flickering onHide?

Tags: material-ui, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to make a Snackbar/Toast appear on button click and disapprear after several seconds. The problem is when Snackbar disapprears there's a flickering with Snackbar without text. How to fix that?

Here's codesandbox to see what I mean: https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-haibt-id7bfg?file=/demo.tsx:601-1510

**Slice:**

```
const initialState: CommonState = {
  alert: {
    isOpen: false,
    type: AlertType.Info,
    message: ""
  }
};

const commonSlice = createSlice({
  name: "common",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    showAlert: (state, action: PayloadAction<Alert>) => {
      state.alert = action.payload;
    },

    hideAlert: (state) => {
      state.alert = null;
    }
  }
});
```

**Component**

```
export default function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
  const { alert } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.common);

  const handleShowAlert = () => {
    dispatch(
      showAlert({
        isOpen: true,
        type: AlertType.Success,
        message: "Text copied message"
      })
    );
  };

  const handleHideAlert = () => {
    dispatch(hideAlert());
  };

  return (
    <Stack spacing={2} sx={{ width: "100%" }}>
      <Button onClick={handleShowAlert}>Show Alert</Button>

      <Snackbar
        open={alert?.isOpen}
        autoHideDuration={3000}
        onClose={handleHideAlert}
        anchorOrigin={{ vertical: "top", horizontal: "center" }}
      >
        <Alert
          onClose={handleHideAlert}
          severity={alert?.type}
          sx={{ width: "100%" }}
        >
          {alert?.message}
        </Alert>
      </Snackbar>
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi, were you able to fix this issue? I have the same issue, can't seem to figure out why

Answer (score 0):

Snackbar flickers without text, because `hideAlert` action has changed `alert` to `null`,
so, `alert?.message` becomes `undefined` (no text).

You can fix it by changing `alert` `isOpen` to `false`, and keep message in `hideAlert` action.

```
hideAlert: (state) => {
   state.alert = {
      ...state.alert,
      isOpen: false
   };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/elastic-wiles-rs4t2q?file=%2Fdemo.tsx%3A22%2C34

This is simply because text change will result in a Alert's change beforehand, which is reflected as a flickering in screen.
You can add a more action or something like I did in the sandbox above. override props that been passed in while keeping others as they are.

Amr Eraky is also right.